# Why We need to derivate by $dy/dx$ and not by $dy/dr$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to find values of "r" in the function

$y=e^{rx}$

to for the equation

$y''- 2y' -3y = 0$

I'm ok to find solution that derivate by "x" but I don't know why I need to derivate by "X" if I need to find "r" values?

The solution I have found by derivating "x" are

`1 & -3`

But if I derivate by "dr" I get something like:

=====

$y' = \left(\frac{dxr}{dr}\right)$

$y' = e^{xr} \left(x \frac{dr}{dr}\right)$

$y' = e^{xr}x$

=====

$y'' = e^{xr}x^2$

=====

$0 = e^{xr}x^2 - 2e^{xr}x - 3e^{xr}$

$0 = e^{xr}(x^2-2x-3)$

And I don't know what I can do now to complete my derivation.

Any idea and explaination about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dylan wrote, $y'$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$. There is no differentiating with respect to $r$.

What you're doing is *guessing* a solution of the form of an answer $y=e^{rx}$. Here, $r$ is some unknown that you wish to eventually find to complete your solution. It doesn't matter what you call it. I could call it $y=e^{\lambda x}$ where $\lambda$ is my parameter instead. Same thing.

Next, you want to actually find out if this form of a solution works, and further, you want to find the specific values for $r$. That's where you substitute into the differential equation:

$$y''- 2y' -3y = 0$$
$$(e^{rx})''- 2(e^{rx})' -3e^{rx} = 0$$

The derivative here is with respect to $x$. Why? Well the problem likely specified that $y=y(x)$.

$$r^2e^{rx}- 2re^{rx} -3e^{rx} = 0$$
$$r^2- 2r -3 = 0$$

This is called the characteristic equation. From it, you can find $r_1=-1$ and $r_2 = 3$. Put these back in your form to find two solutions

$$y_1 = e^{-x}, \quad\quad y_2 = e^{3x}$$

The final solution is a linear combination of these.

$$y = c_1 e^{-x}+ c_2e^{3x}$$

Comment: awesome! Thanks for your explanation. It's pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

You're solving for $y$ as a function of $x$ and $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ in the equation. $r$ is just a parameter.